# can javascript get value from MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i am using asp.net mvc 3. in one my of page. i need to get a list of string from a list object.
so i do this:

```
@{
    var orderIds  = from s in Model.Orders
                    select s.id;

}
```

and from one of my ajax call, i will need "orderIds "

```
$("#renderBtn").click(function () {
            var inputData = {
                'orderIds':  need to get the order ids here 
            }; 

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Order/ExtraData',
                data: inputData,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    ....
                },
                error: function () {
                    ...
                }
            });
        });
```

any idea how can i get orderIds and use in javascripts?
Thanks

Comment: the controller needs to give this information to the view (which is the jquery code). so create a route `/Order/ExtraData` for this controller. (i don't know asp.net, so i can't give you more details)

Comment: i construct a hidden value, the view populate value and store in hidden filed.. then javascript read from it.. solve my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code aboce defining `orderIds` is a server-side variable; what you need us a client-side variable. You'll need to define that variable at the creation of the view, in a `script` block near the bottom of the page.

```
@{ 
  var orderIds = string.Join(",", Model.Orders.Select(s => s.id).ToArray());
}
<script>
       var orderIds  = [@orderIds]
</script>
```

*Caveat: The code may not be perfect, and may not compile, but that should give you an idea how to proceed.*

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't (or don't want to) using inline javascript and keep it all separated you could do something like this:

```
@{ 
  var orderIds = string.Join(",", Model.Orders.Select(s => s.id).ToArray());
}

<input type="hidden" id="orderIds" value="@orderIds" />
```

And then in your javascript/jQuery:

```
orderIds = $('#orderIds').val();
```